# Using Jquery History Plugin to solve thickbox browser back button problem

Tags: jquery, thickbox

Some of you may be aware of the "problem" with Jquery plugins such thickbox , Lightbox,Fancybox etc.) where some users consider the back button to be broken. Basically, after loading a image/vid in thickbox, if you press the browser back button, it takes the user back to the page *before* the one they used to launch the image/vid, rather than that page itself.

If thats unclear, navigate to http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/ (having already visited any other page in that browser tab first!) hit one of the demos and, once its loaded, press the back button - you will see what I mean.

There is a lot of discussion around whether this is in fact "broken", however, I need to find a "solution" regardless.

Im looking at using the jquery-history-plugin but am not having much luck at all.

Does anyone have any experience of combining these two? (or even with Lightbox etc.) or with any other method thatb might be of use to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem I see with fixing this 'broken' behaviour is that around 50% of your users will consider the back-button broken if it *doesn't* return them to the previous page in the history. So you've got an issue where you *can* 'fix' it, but could easily take more work than it's worth.

Comment: I very much agree with this, however the decision of whether to "fix" it or not is no longer mine to make (for various reasons).
Thanks for confirming my thoughts! :) But if anyone has any experience with setting up something similar, that would be awesome!